# Orientation of tabs component does not work in RadixUI

Tags: reactjs, radix

I am using RadixUI and there is `orientation` props, which could be vertically set. I tried to use this prop and expect that thabs will be aligned in column but it does not work:

```
  <Tabs.Root orientation="vertical" className="TabsRoot" defaultValue="tab1">
```

Question: Did someone faced this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: orientation is not for UI, but for functionality. Read more here https://github.com/radix-ui/website/issues/463

Comment: @unhackit, thanks for your comment, could you please post it as an answer to accept it?

Comment: alright, I have done that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Radix UI, they are a style-free library, which means that the orientation prop does not change the UI. You would need to apply the styles. `vertical` means that the up / down arrow will move focus within the component

You can read more about the functionality here https://github.com/radix-ui/website/issues/463